# Angular js - pop up value not reflected in ng-model, and not able to close

Tags: angularjs, popup, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

I am trying to add the mark details of student and the teachers comments about the student using angular js, as below.

I have inlcuded pop up component from my controllers.js at run time based on click event on an icon . At run time, I am able to see the pop up after clicking the icon. But it is too small.

1. I am not able to type any value to the popup
2. If I try to edit from the 'Inspect Element' option from the browser, then also its not reflecting to the model 'student.notes'
3. Most importantly, I am not able to close the popup.

My html is as below.

```
<div class="ui accordion" ng-repeat="student in students">
<input type="text" size="3" placeholder="TotalMarks" ng-model="student.total"></input>
<input type="text" size="2" placeholder="Rank" ng-model="student.rank"></input>
<i class="edit icon" ng-click="showTeachersComments($event)"></i>
</div>
```

**Teacher.js** - controller

```
function _showTeachersComments($event) {
                    var elem = angular.element(**templates.teacherComments**);
                    $compile(elem)($scope);
                    $scope.batsmanCommentId = $event.target.id;
                    console.log("commentid");
                    console.log($scope.batsmanCommentId);
                    $($event.target)
                        .popup({
                            html: elem,
                            closable: false,
                            position: 'bottom left',
                            on: ''
                        })
                        .popup('show');
                }

 function _closeTeachersComment($event, note) {
                    console.log("note =");
                    console.log(note);
                    $scope.battingEntry.notes = note;
                    $('#' + $scope.batsmanCommentId).popup('hide');
                };

function _init(){
$scope.showTeachersComments=_showTeachersComments;
$scope.closeTeachersComment=_closeTeachersComment;
}
```

I have a template.js linking templates.teacherComments to popupTeacherComment.html.

**popupTeacherComment.html**

```
<form class="ui form" id="teacherNotesForm">
      <div class="field">
        <label for="">Comments</label>
        <textarea ng-model="**notes**" rows="1" cols="50" name="Comment"></textarea>
      </div>  
      <div class="ui secondary small menu">
        <div class="right small menu">
        <a class="item" href="" ng-click="closeTeacherComment($event,notes)">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using angular-ui for this, why not use the `$modal` service?

As i see, you don't give the popup any id.

```
var elem = angular.element(**templates.teacherComments**);
$compile(elem)($scope);
$scope.batsmanCommentId = $event.target.id;
$(elem).attr("id", $scope.batsmanCommentId); // <-- this is missing to select it later on
console.log("commentid");
```

I guess, that's why you can't close it.

And yeah, it can't reflect `student.notes` because you compile the view with the controllers scope. In the controllers scope, it will search for `student.notes` and there won't be any variable called like this.

I'd recomment to move this code (since using jquery within the controller is a bad practice) into a directive and pass the students into the isolated scope.

```
<div class="ui accordion" ng-repeat="student in students" comment-popout comment-popout-student="student">     
</div>
```

And the directive:

```
app.directive("commentPopout", function($compile){
  return {
    scope: {
      "commentPopoutStudent": "="
    },
    template: '<input type="text" size="3" placeholder="TotalMarks" ng-model="commentPopoutStudent.total"></input>
     <input type="text" size="2" placeholder="Rank" ng-model="commentPopoutStudent.rank"></input>
     <i class="edit icon" ng-click="openPopout()"></i>',
     link: function($scope, $element){
          $scope.openPopout = function(){
              var elem = angular.element(**templates.teacherComments**);
              $compile(elem)($scope);
              $($event.target).popup({
                            html: elem,
                            closable: false,
                            position: 'bottom left',
                            on: ''
                        })
                        .popup('show');
          }
     }

  }
});
```

And the templates variables in ng-model need to be named like in the directive:

```
<form class="ui form" id="teacherNotesForm">
      <div class="field">
        <label for="">Comments</label>
        <textarea ng-model="commentPopoutStudent.notes" rows="1" cols="50" name="Comment"></textarea>
      </div>  
      <div class="ui secondary small menu">
        <div class="right small menu">
        <a class="item" href="" ng-click="closeTeacherComment($event,notes)">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Note that this code is untested and just a suggestion how you can implement it.